# xml drawable not being drawn properly in android

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I want a non-veg icon to drawn using drawable xml resource in android. I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0

The preview is being shown perfectly in my android studio. but it's not beind displayed correctly in my devices. Please help me.

**Here is what I want**

[image: what I want]

**Here is what I'm getting**

*Android 5.0.0*
[image: Android 5.0.0]

*Android 4.4.4*
[image: Android 4.4.4]

*Android 4.3*
[image]

**Here is by xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:thickness="2dp">
            <size
                android:width="24dp"
                android:height="24dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dip"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="-1">
            <padding
                android:bottom="15dp"
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp"
                android:top="15dp" />

            <size
                android:width="4dp"
                android:height="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an oval for your second item, not a ring. Don't bother specifying size or padding on the second item, it's going to be scaled to the size of the first item anyway, use offsets on the item tag instead. Don't specify thickness on the rectangle, it does nothing as it is a ring-only attribute.

The modified xml below gives roughly the shape you're looking for. Adjust the dimensions to fine tune the appearance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size
                android:height="24dp"
                android:width="24dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```